# Show that this Set contains all multiples of a whole number

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let S be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose S satisfies the following constraints

If $x,y \in S$ then $x+y \in S $

If $x \in S$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $xy \in S$

Show that S is the set of all integer multiples of m for some $m \in \mathbb{N}\cup{\{0\}} $

So far I can think of a few things that might be useful, this might be a proof by cases where we split it up into the case where $ S\cap\mathbb{N} =\emptyset$ and $ S\cap\mathbb{N} \neq\emptyset$ which is when $m=0,m\neq 0$ respectively. But how do I use the constraints to come to that conclusion? I don't need a full solution but a hint would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be the minimal positive in $S$. Then by the second rule $km\in S$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: What would the first rule contribute to the proof at all? Would you use it to somehow prove that S does not contain numbers that are not multiples of m? Oh because m is the minimal positive that means every other element has to conform to the rules. The addition rule doesn't change anything because you can factor an m?

Comment: if $\mu$ would be another member in $S$ gotta be $\mu>m$ then $\mu+(-m)$ would be in $S$ and $\mu+(-rm)<m$ for some $r$ but $\mu+(-rm)\in S$ enters in contradiction with the choice of $m$

Comment: So basically if $\mu > m $ that is coprime to m, then we can pick an $r$ such that $ 0 < \mu +(-rm) < m $ and when we chose $m$ it was the minimal element so that proves uniqueness of multiples of m, correct?

Comment: yes,  the solution for that contradiction is that $\mu$ be a multiple of $m$

Comment: @janmarqz without using well-ordering principle or some such thing, how do you know that such a minimal $m$ exists in $S$?

Comment: @AnuragA: In the beginning it says: nonempty subset of *Ganzen-Zahlen* and yes, we are implicitly employing well-ordering

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

First do the trivial case $S=\{0\}$. Then move onto the non-trivial case.

Let $T \subseteq S$, where $T=\{a \in S \, | \, a > 0\}$. Now use well-ordering principle to claim that $T$ has a smallest element. Call it $m$, use that to show that $S=m\mathbb{Z}$.